# Meteor / iron-router subscribing published data

Tags: meteor, publish, iron-router, subscribe

I need help with this issue.

I have two test publication **schools** and **schoolsByLanguageId**

```
Meteor.publish 'schools', ->
  return School.find({"schoolId" : 710185197})

Meteor.publish "schoolsByLanguageId", (languageId) ->
  check languageId, String    
  return School.find({language: languageId})
```

and this test route:

```
  @route 'schoolsByLanguage',
    path: '/schools/language/:languageId'
    layoutTemplate: 'leftNavLayout'
    yieldTemplates: 'schoolsLeftNav': to: 'leftNav'
    onBeforeAction: (pause) -> pause() unless @ready()
    waitOn: ->
#       [Meteor.subscribe 'schoolsByLanguageId', @params.languageId]
      [Meteor.subscribe('schools')]
    data: -> {
        schools: School.where({})
    }
```

When I use **[Meteor.subscribe('schools')]** subscription, I get data, but in case of this one **[Meteor.subscribe 'schoolsByLanguageId', @params.languageId]** NOT.

path is: /schools/language/300

What I am doing wrong?.

Thaks in advance.
Patrik

**SOLVED:**

Argument was parsed as a String and I used it in publish function as Number. It just helped me to parseInt(languageId)

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log languageId` at the top of your `schoolsByLanguageId` publish function?

Comment: Just a guess, but should that be `check languageId, "String"` ?

Comment: See whether `languageId` is not automatically parsed as a number.

Comment: It looks that there is a problem with this check
`check languageId, String`
because when I set `laguageId` directly to for example to 270, publish function return the result correctly.

`return School.find({'language': 270})`

Comment: Thanks to all, I found out solution.
Argument was parsed as a String and I used it in publish function as Number.

It just helped me to parseInt(languageId).